# Trying to run grep comman using exec

Tags: c++, grep, exec

I am trying to run the grep command in my child process after fork system call. It displays an error: grep: *.*: No such file or directory. My code for exec is below:

```
execl("/bin/grep","grep","a","*.*",NULL);
```

If i replace * . * with a file name it works fine. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `*.*` is passed on to `grep` literally. It's not interpreted by the shell - so `grep` tries to open a file named `*.*` (and fails).

If you want to do shell like *globbing* from within your program, you could take a look at the `glob` functions:

```
#include <glob.h>

int glob(const char *pattern, int flags,
         int (*errfunc) (const char *epath, int eerrno),
         glob_t *pglob);

void globfree(glob_t *pglob);
```